# EndRequest - Context.Response.StatusCode is always 200 (even when it should be 404)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to implement 404 handling as described here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9026941/131809

In my `EndRequest` block, I have this:

```
public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_EndRequest()
    {
        if (Context.Response.StatusCode == 404)
        {
         //do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

However, the StatusCode **always** equals 200, even if I try to visit a url that definitely doesn't exist (/keyboardcat for example)

The 'default' .net 404 page is still displayed however

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This only happened when using Cassini
When switching to IIS, this was no longer that case